# Frobenius Theorem 1897

Tags: reference-request, linear-transformations, math-history

Where can I find the proof of Frobenius's theorem in 1897 about linear transformation from the complex nxn matrices preserving the determinant?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/522/linear-transformation-that-preserves-the-determinant?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Look at M. Marcus, B. Moyls, Linear Transformations on Algebras of Matrices, Canadian Journal of Mathematics, 1959.
Try to reach out to V. Troitsky (Calgary or U of Alberta)... He had a nice proof which presumably he'd adapted from Marcus and Moyls.